# Two network interface bridges - one LAN

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, bridge, bridge-router

I have little bit lack of linux networking understanding, so there is my question:

We have 2 computers (SRV1, SRV2).

Each of it has 1 NIC and both are connected by OpenVPN bridge

Configuration:

SRV1:

```
openvpnbr0 - 172.16.13.1
vmbr0 - 172.16.1.1
```

SRV1:

```
openvpnbr0 - 172.16.13.2
vmbr0 - 172.16.2.1
```

Both interfaces openvpnbr0 and vmbr0 are bridges, both of it should work as single network (172.16.0.0)

Is it possible approach?

Now the problem is when I ping 172.16.13.2 from 172.16.13.1 it tries to use 172.16.2.1 instead of 172.16.1.1

If there is needed more info - I will be glad to provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use only one bridge, there is no sense to use two bridges to do what you want. Remove all the interfaces from one bridge and add them to the other one.

Comment: How are the 2 servers physically connected?  You seem to be have a bridge for supporting virtual machines?  What hypervisor are you using?

Comment: @diegows, you're right, with 1 bridge (vmbr0) passed by openvpn all works, thanks!

Comment: @Zoredache, servers are connected by openvpn too, we use Proxmox with openvz and KVM virtualization.

Comment: @Anton,ok I'll write my comment as answer. Please, set this as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only one bridge, there is no sense to use two bridges to do what you want. Remove all the interfaces from one bridge and add them to the other one.